# How do I count the number of times a column consecutively decreases in value

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet where a column contains a person's weight. I want to count how many times in a row their weight has decreased in consecutive entries for both the current weight and all time, so:

```
108
107
106
105
104
106
104
103
```

Should return 3 as it's decreased three times in a row at the end, and also 5 as it decreased 5 times in a row at the start. Those values are in a column not a row in the sheet. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have an example of code / a formula you've tried?

Comment: The closest I've come so far is generating an array of true/false containing if the streak (I've realised this is what I'm looking for) continues. I think I'm on the right track, I'd rather do it without relying on the date column A as it would be nice to be able to handle multiple entries for the same date. =ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), if(match(Log!A2:A, Log!$A2:$A)>1, vlookup(Log!A2:A-1, {Log!$A2:$A, Log!$B2:B}, 2, false) > Log!B2:B,), ))

Comment: Relying on having one entry per day of consecutive days, this works: =match(false,index(sort(ArrayFormula({Log!A2:A, if(len(Log!A2:A), if(match(Log!A2:A, Log!$A2:$A)>1, vlookup(Log!A2:A-1, {Log!$A2:$A, Log!$B2:B}, 2, false) > Log!B2:B, true), )} ), 1, false), 0,2),0) - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste in **D2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN({A2; A2:A}), IF(B2:B901 < {1000; B2:B900}, 1, ), ))
```

paste in **E2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D901=1,
 MMULT(N(ROW(D2:D901)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(D2:D901))), N(D2:D901=1))-HLOOKUP(0,
 MMULT(N(ROW(D2:D901)> TRANSPOSE(ROW(D2:D901))), N(D2:D901=1)), MATCH(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(D2:D901), IF(N(D2:D901<>D1:D900), ROW(D2:D901), ), 1, 1),
 VLOOKUP(ROW(D2:D901), IF(N(D2:D901<>D1:D900), ROW(D2:D901), ), 1, 1), 0), 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

and make sure your sheet has a minimum of 901 rows

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to do without the helper column? I've tried using Query and Indirect inside the ArrayFormula but discovered the strings don't update when passed to these functions.

Comment: not really, but you can put them on another sheet (sheet2) and hide whole sheet. or just hide those helpers only

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the current streak without a helper column, it also calculates the days the streak has continued for (which wasn't what I asked but is better for me). Not sure if answering my own question is the right response here, I'm not experienced with this website.

```
=iferror(sum(query(query({Log!A2:A, ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), if(row(Log!A2:A) > 2, Log!A2:A - offset(Log!A2:A, -1,,counta(Log!A2:A)+1 ),0 ), )), ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), if(row(Log!A2:A) > 2, if(len(Log!B2:B), Log!B2:B < offset(Log!B2:B, -1,,counta(Log!B2:B)+1 ), true),TRUE ), )), Log!B2:B}, "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc limit " & match(False, query(query({Log!A2:A, ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), if(row(Log!A2:A) > 2, Log!A2:A - offset(Log!A2:A, -1,,counta(Log!A2:A)+1 ),0 ), )), ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), if(row(Log!A2:A) > 2, if(len(Log!B2:B), Log!B2:B < offset(Log!B2:B, -1,,counta(Log!B2:B)+1 ), true),TRUE ), )), Log!B2:B}, "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc"), "select Col3"), 0)-1), "select Col2")), 0)
```

And to count the max streak:

```
=max(transpose(index(query({0}, "select " & join(",", unique(transpose(split(substitute(join(" + ", query({Log!A2:A, ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), if(row(Log!A2:A) > 2, if(Log!B2:B < offset(Log!B2:B, -1,,counta(Log!B2:B)+1,), Log!A2:A - offset(Log!A2:A, -1,,counta(Log!A2:A)+1 ), 0),0 ), )), ArrayFormula(if(len(Log!A2:A), if(row(Log!A2:A) > 2, if(len(Log!B2:B), Log!B2:B < offset(Log!B2:B, -1,,counta(Log!B2:B)+1 ), false),false ), )), Log!B2:B}, "select Col2 where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc")), " + 0 + ", ","), ","))))), 2)))
```